# div inmutable dentro de un div content-editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css

### Planteamiento

Quisiera hacer un `div` que fuera totalmente **inmodificable**, de preferencia, *inseleccionable* e *inenfocable* incluso si se encuentra dentro de un elemento que tenga habilitado el atributo `contentEditable`.

Nota: No puedo optar por poner el div fuera y posicionarlo con posición absoluta, debido a que necesito posicionarlo en forma relativa al contenedor superior.

### Intentos

De momento he intentado con la moderna propiedad `pointer-events`, pero moviendo las flechas se puede burlar.
Así que como parche he intentado que al modificar el texto regrese a su valor original programáticamente.

```js
var modificadoporcodigo = false;
$('#encabezado').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
  /*console.log(e.which);
  if (e.keyCode == 46 || e.keyCode == 46) {
    alert('Lo sentimos, los encabezados no se pueden borrar');
  }*/
  if (modificadoporcodigo) {
    modificadoporcodigo = false;
  } else {
    $('#encabezado').text('Prueba');
    modificadoporcodigo = true;
  }
});
```

```css
#encabezado {
  color: gray;
  position: absolute;
  top: 27px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fondoCuerpo" class="col col-md-12">
  <div class="Hojas" contentEditable="true">
    <div id="encabezado">Prueba</div>
    Hola Mundo!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Solo para satisfacer mi curiosidad, porque necesitas hacer eso?

Comment: @jasilva para poner texto de margen en cada hoja de un editor html5 :) PD: el que hace las preguntas soy yo.. ok no :P

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro es que en si la pregunta es interesante, pero no me imaginaba un caso "de la vida real" ;)

Comment: @rnrneverdies si le sirve de información para responder la pregunta, es una aplicación pensada para que la usen abogados, así que dudo que intenten ver el código fuente de la página o abrir el inspector. Saludos.

Comment: No me parece necesario borrar, ya que c/u es libre de comentar como le parezca, pero SI se puede ocultar con la posibilidad de que el usuario lo lea o no, mejor.

Comment: @JamesPeter me parece que a futuros usuarios no les sirven de nada estos comentarios... para que los dejaria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando la propiedad con CSS3:

```
.no-seleccionable {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Aunque esto no es para todos los navegadores y lo que quieres es algo que requiere probarse en todas habiendo muchas soluciones.

Solo con CSS podrás lo que quieres. Quizás si el contenido lo pongas en el atributo title para luego mostrarlo con `CSS2+` se pudiera también.

Observa:

```css
.no-seleccionable:before {
  content: attr(title)": ";
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div contentEditable="true" class="no-seleccionable" title="tu texto aqui">
  Hola Mundo
</div>
```

Comment: No me sirvió, pero gracias por tu tiempo. En chrome que es el navegador que más me importa, `-webkit-user-select ` se puede bypassear simplemente moviendo las teclas y escribiendo dentro. Modificar el contenido antes del elemento es mucho más sensato, pero produce algunos problemas cuando tienes div de pié de página y div de encabezado, en concreto se puede borrar el pie, y si le intentas mucho, al borrar el texto tu cursor se pasa al div de encabezado haciendo que el texto se encime junto después. http://postimg.org/image/yglopqngb/

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro fíjate en el snippet, al parecer hace lo que quieres. ni se puede seleccionar ni se puede modificar.

Comment: @rnrneverdies Su amable edición destructiva resolvió el problema, al señor James le había entendido al leer en órden las preguntas que su aporte era hacer no editable el contenido interno, debería volver su edición otra respuesta agregándole `position:absolute` y `margin-left:50%`, pues mediante `:before` y `:after` pude hacer encabezado y pie de página fácilmente como puede apreciar en la imágen: http://postimg.org/image/6z99hq6ud/ .

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro, de tu ejemplo anterior: `<div id="encabezado">Prueba</div>`  Prueba con `<div id="encabezado" class="no-seleccionable" title="Prueba"></div>` Con eso, no se puede seleccionar y usa las 2 clases definidas arriba.

Comment: Upps... no vi tu comentario después de la mía, mientras comentaba. Pero en fin. Ya resolviste.

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro mi edición fue estándar, solo cambie el ejemplo a stack snippet, si a James le molesta puede hacer el rollback cuando quiera.

Comment: Gracias estimado @JamesPeter, el primer comentario muestra una imágen de cuando intenté precisamente eso que siguiere. Gracias por su valiosa ayuda.

Comment: @rnrneverdies De hecho le agregó `contentEditable` sin notarlo, si aún así lo consideras como un error trivial, entonces con su permiso voy a aceptar la respuesta del honorable `JamesPeter` ¿Le parece acertado?

Comment: No hay razón de molestia, ya que la acción fue intento de ayuda. Saludos y continúa con tu proyecto que también estoy en terribles problemas :D

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro es cierto, jjaaj.. fue para probar el punto. La cuestion fue que TU no te diste cuenta que James te dio la respuesta correcta. Disculpa si intente hacerte notar tu error sin agregar otra respuesta innecesaria.

Comment: Apreciable @rnrneverdies como podrá notar por los comentarios anteriores, ambos James y tu servidor teníamos un enfoque errado a pesar de tener la respuesta correcta. Gracias por pensar fuera de la caja.

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro a seguir divirtiéndose entonces!

Comment: Los 3 estuvimos errados :D:D:D

Comment: de acuerdo! ! !

Comment: Quien errara como @rnrneverdies todo el tiempo! :D